# Run Time Error 3144 Syntax Error in UPDATE statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got an error on update on SQL statement in access VBA.
Here is the code:

```
Dim id As Integer, docNo As String, pNo As String
id = Me.txtID.Value
pNo = Me.txtPENo.Value
docNo = Me.txtdocNo.Value
db.Execute ("UPDATE tblPE SET (PENo='" & pNo & "',DocNo='" & docNo & "') WHERE ID=" & id & ";")
```

Comment: Remove the `SET` parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

For readability and maintainiability, consider parameterization via [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao) and avoid concatenating and punctuating VBA variables within SQL:

```
Dim db As Database, qdef As QueryDef
Dim sql As String

' PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
sql = "PARAMETERS [prm_pNo] TEXT, [prm_docNo] TEXT, [prm_id] INTEGER;" _
       & "UPDATE tblPE SET PENo=[prm_pNo], DocNo=[prm_docNo] WHERE ID=[prm_id];"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", sql)

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!prm_id = Me.txtID.Value
qdef!prm_pNo = Me.txtPENo.Value
qdef!prm_docNo = Me.txtdocNo.Value

' EXECUTE ACTION
qdef.Execute

' RELEASE RESOURCES
Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the extra brackets in the SQL statement. Instead, try:

```
    db.Execute ("UPDATE tblPE SET PENo='" & pNo & "',DocNo='" & docNo & "' WHERE ID=" & id & ";")
```

Regards,